# Grails 2.4.0 unable to resolve class org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils in intellijIdea 13

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I want to parse url string and extract parameters.
So I decided to use URLEncodedUtils class which is already present in grails 2.4.0.

Code

`String url = "~/Dashboard/User/MyDashboard.jsp?firstname=pankaj&lastname=shinde"
List<NameValuePair> params11 = URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(XMLDefinations[0]), "UTF-8");`

error when I try to run grails app from command line.

`unable to resolve class org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils
 @ line 2, column 1.
   import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils
   ^`

I already cleaned app.
Jars are available in IDE.

Help?